# How to run cumulative totals by date with multiple groupings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have several year's worth of daily profits for different portfolios and strategies. For every date, portfolio and strategy I'd like to see the daily profit (not calculated as this is already available), as well as the MTD, QTD, YTD and LTD values. I had accomplished this with some nested while loops but takes forever and I'm fairly confident this could be accomplished with some joins. If someone could walk me through it would be greatly appreciated. A simplified version of the exercise is below. With the first 4 columns already available, and the right for are what I'm looking to accomplish:

| Date | GROUP_1 | GROUP_2 | Daily Profits | MTD | QTD | YTD | LTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-15 | A | X | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-19 | A | X | 5 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 2021-01-20 | A | X | 2 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 2021-01-24 | A | X | 5 | 13 | 13 | 13 | 13 |
| 2021-02-19 | A | X | 5 | 5 | 18 | 18 | 18 |
| 2021-02-23 | A | Y | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 2021-03-21 | A | X | 1 | 1 | 19 | 19 | 19 |
| 2021-03-25 | A | Y | 5 | 5 | 9 | 9 | 9 |
| 2021-04-20 | A | X | 5 | 5 | 5 | 24 | 24 |
| 2021-04-24 | A | Y | 2 | 2 | 2 | 11 | 11 |
| 2021-05-20 | A | X | 3 | 3 | 8 | 27 | 27 |
| 2021-05-24 | A | Y | 4 | 4 | 6 | 15 | 15 |
| 2021-01-15 | B | Y | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 2021-01-19 | B | Y | 3 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 2021-01-20 | B | Y | 1 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 |
| 2021-01-24 | B | Y | 2 | 11 | 11 | 11 | 11 |
| 2021-02-19 | B | Y | 4 | 4 | 15 | 15 | 15 |
| 2021-02-23 | B | Y | 5 | 9 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 2021-03-21 | B | Y | 1 | 1 | 21 | 21 | 21 |
| 2021-03-25 | B | Y | 1 | 2 | 22 | 22 | 22 |
| 2021-04-20 | B | Y | 4 | 4 | 4 | 26 | 26 |
| 2021-04-24 | B | Y | 5 | 9 | 9 | 31 | 31 |
| 2021-05-20 | B | Y | 1 | 1 | 10 | 32 | 32 |
| 2021-05-24 | B | Y | 2 | 3 | 12 | 34 | 34 |

Comment: `sum(daily_profits) over(partition by group_1, group_2, year(date), datepart(quarter, date) order by date) as QTD`

Comment: Thanks, will try that out!

Comment: @lptr Probably best to add `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` otherwise could get incorrect results if there are duplicate dates. It's also faster

Comment: @Charlieface, I'm unfamiliar. Would you mind showing how that would be used?

Comment: `sum(daily_profits) over(partition by group_1, group_2, year(date), datepart(quarter, date) order by date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as QTD` because the default is `RANGE` not `ROWS` see eg https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/01/22/sql-server-windowing-functions-rows-vs-range/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following SQL script should do the trick:

```sql
select 
  value_date,
  group_1,
  group_2,
  daily_profits,
  sum(daily_profits) over (partition by datepart(yy, value_date), datepart(mm, value_date), group_1, group_2 order by value_date, group_1, group_2 rows unbounded preceding) as MTD,
  sum(daily_profits) over (partition by datepart(yy, value_date), datepart(qq, value_date), group_1, group_2 order by value_date, group_1, group_2 rows unbounded preceding) as QTD,
  sum(daily_profits) over (partition by datepart(yy, value_date), group_1, group_2 order by value_date, group_1, group_2 rows unbounded preceding) as YTD,
  sum(daily_profits) over (partition by group_1, group_2 order by value_date, group_1, group_2 rows unbounded preceding) as LTD
from agg_profit
order by value_date, group_1, group_2
```

SQL Fiddle for reference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d6c5f/1

Documentation is found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `EOMONTH` probably easier than `DATEPART(mm`, on the other hand because you have multiple `SUM OVER`s, you might avoid an extra sort by using `DATEPART` a second time